# jQuery: Order Inside .contents()

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do this:

```
function getAllTextNodes(root) {
  root = $(root || "body");
  return root.find("*:not(iframe)").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && //Node.TEXT_NODE = 3
      $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== "";
  });
}

getAllTextNodes($.parseHTML("<div><div>a<div>sub</div>b</div></div>"))
```

the result is an array with "a", "b" and "sub". So it seems that they traverse the structure and when they reach an element they work on that element **entirely before** they continue with the nested elements.

While this may make sense (or it doesn't matter in some cases) it causes some troubles on my end, because I need a logic that returns the elements in the exact same order they appear in the DOM-tree, i.e. I'd be happy to see "a", "sub" and "b" being returned.

Is that something that jQuery built on purpose? Can I change the order somehow? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that something that jQuery built on purpose? Or is this a bug?

I don't think it's done on purpose, but given that selector APIs and even most modification methods do have their results in DOM order, it might be considered a bug. From what you show, it looks like `contents` is implemented with a simple `flatMap(el => el.childNodes)`.

> Can I change the order somehow?

Yes, you can use [`jQuery.uniqueSort()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.uniqueSort/) on the jQuery object, which uses [`Node.compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition) internally:

```
return $.uniqueSort(root.find("*:not(iframe)").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== "";
}));
```

However, jQuery isn't great with text nodes anyway. It might be simpler to use a native DOM API here, such as [`NodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator):

```
const it = document.createNodeIterator(root[0], NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, node => node.data.trim() != ""),
      res = [];
for (let node; node = it.nextNode(); )
    res.push(node);
return res;
```